# Can you cube between multiple relations in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to find the combination given another variable:

Example:

```
name, group, points  
jim,    T,    12
steven, T,    10
ting,   T,    15
matt,   F,    16
aamir,  F,    12
```

I want to be able to get all combinations between members of T and F and do some multiplication to the points column for that. I first thought to break this into two relations, i.e. a T and an F relation and do some combination between them using CUBE but i don't think you can use CUBE between relations? Any suggestions?

Results:

```
jim,     matt,   12*16
jim,     aamir,  12*12
steven,  matt,   16*16
...
...
ting,    aamir,  15*12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input.txt**

```
jim,T,12
steven,T,10
ting,T,15
matt,F,16
aamir,F,12
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, group:chararray, points:int);
B = FILTER A BY group=='T';
C = FILTER A BY group=='F';
D = CROSS B,C;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE B::name,C::name,B::points*C::points;
DUMP E;
```

**Output**:

```
(jim,matt,192)
(jim,aamir,144)
(steven,matt,160)
(steven,aamir,120)
(ting,matt,240)
(ting,aamir,180)
```